# Wordpress Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have combined bootstrap and wordpress. I have found 2 articles and gists that provide a walker and some markup to add to get a dropdown navigational menu working properly.

I have tried several times to incorporate the walker, but all I get is just a blank vertical menu that can't be seen except for bullets. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Ok, here is what I have done. http://twittem.github.com/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/ I have followed the instructions here.  I created a new twitter_bootstrap_nav_walker.php file, just like it said. I have placed it in the correct place. The wp_nav_menu() (code), I wasn't sure where to put this, one person said to put it into mt header, another said to put it in nav_menu_template.php. When I put it to the template, I get a syntax error within dreamweaver. When I added the code to the header.php file, I get a fatal error. Scott, thanks for showing me something new but I am not looking to start over

Comment: The way this was phrased it was too open. Select your best attempt and try to make a concrete question with some code. That way you'll increase the odds of getting help.

Comment: use this instead: http://www.rootstheme.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup/code below is working for me. You may or may not want the user login code in the header.

in header.php

```
        <div id="page-navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                            <a href="/wp-admin" class="login"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></a>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <a href="/wp-login.php" class="login"><i class="icon-signin"></i> Sign In</a>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </p>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav',
                    'walker' => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                    )); ?>   

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu class comes from [John Megahan](http://goodandorgreat.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/update-4-using-twitter-bootstrap-2-0-dropdown-menus-with-wordpress/).

```
class Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output    .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";

}

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $li_attributes = '';
    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = ($args->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
    $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;


    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ($args->has_children)        ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= ($args->has_children) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

    if ( !$element )
        return;

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

    //display this element
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) ) 
        $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    else if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) 
        $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] ); 
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

    $id = $element->$id_field;

    // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
    if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

        foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

            if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
                $newlevel = true;
                //start the child delimiter
                $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
            }
            $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
        }
        unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
    }

    if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
        //end the child delimiter
        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }

    //end this element
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I have done this repeatedly. I have seen every post on the topic, I followed every instuction (even yours) and nothing, keep getting errors all the way.  I think it is time to scrap this project and take a different route.  I have wasted enough of my life on this!  Thanks all for trying to help.

Comment: Don't give up! Put in the header markup without the custom walker, i.e. delete the line 'walker' => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu() and the comma on the previous line. You should see a bootstrap style menu but the 2nd level items will also appear below the top level items. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, the menu finally appeared just as you said. Thank you. But shouldn't it inherit the appropriate classes and layout like bootstrap intended? What is it that I need to change to get it to look and act right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The next step is to create the  Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu.php and include it. Put the following line into functions.php: `require_once(get_template_directory() . "/inc/bootstrap_nav_menu_walker.php");` This assumes that the file is in an `/inc` folder. If the site now runs without error, the final step is to add the `'walker' => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu()` line to the `wp_nav_menu` call.